# Не применяются стили к элементу CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Вот написал новый код, тоже самое

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Flat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
            <div class="M_logo">M</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}


div.header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1680px;
    height: 100px;
}


div.logo {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 164px;
}


div.M-logo {
    font-size: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Проверил валидатором, ошибки в html коде: https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/check#css3-validator_error      ;  https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/check#css3-validator_error

Answer (score 3):

Вам не нужно писать `div` / `nav` перед (точкой) названием класса:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.top_part {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1680px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #d20000;
}

.bottom_part {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1680px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #ffcc00;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1680px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("../images/background.jpg") center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.top_nav {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  
  background-color: lightblue;

}

a {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="top_part">
    <nav class="top_nav">
      <a href="#">English</a>
      <a href="#">Contact Center</a>
      <a href="#">Contry Profile</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom_part"></div>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

> Предполагаю, что запутался с наследством, родителями.

Наследования от "родителя" для `.top-nav` у Вас вообще не присутствует

Comment: Нет, всё как было, так и осталось.... Всегда писал через привычный мне синтаксис и было всё норм, вряд ли дело в нём

Comment: Я через валидатор проверял, в css файле всё правильно. А в html было написано "Ошибка разбора"  и был скопирован мой код Html

Comment: @Lirika что именно не работает? В моем примере свойство `background-color` успешно применено